# Is there a popular name for this concatenated expression?

Tags: list, concatenation, expression

if there is two lists such as [[a, b, c], [d, e]]

we can rewrite above two lists like [3, a, b, c, 2, d, e]

is there a name for this concatenated expression?

Comment: How do you make the first list to second list?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard name for it. You can use a name that says exactly what it is. "Concatenated count-prefixed lists."